# Why Drop $\forall x \in \mathbb{X}$ in delta-epsilon definition at infinity?

Tags: calculus, limits

For a function $$f:X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$$
My course notes says that:

$$\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) = l \Leftrightarrow (\forall \epsilon > 0, \exists S \in \mathbb{R}, x> S \implies |f(x)-l| < \epsilon)$$

I don't understand why we have dropped the $$\forall x \in X$$

In other words, why is it not this:
$$\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) = l \Leftrightarrow (\forall \epsilon > 0, \exists S \in \mathbb{R}, \forall x \in X, x> S \implies |f(x)-l| < \epsilon)$$

Wouldn't we want the implication to hold true for ***all*** $x$ larger than $S$, analogous to when we're dealing with the definition of limits as $x$ approaches $a$?

$$\lim_{x \to a} f(x) = l \Leftrightarrow (\forall \epsilon > 0, \exists \delta > 0, \forall x \in X, 0 < |x-a| < \delta \implies |f(x)-l| < \epsilon)$$

Otherwise, I could just find a really small $S$, smaller than a $x_1$ where $f(x_1)=l$ and if it works for one particular $x$, I could claim the limit as $x \rightarrow \infty$ is $l$, which is clearly not the intended definition of a limit as $x$ approaches infinity.

Comment: It should be. It wasn't written explicitly in the notes, but it should be there, just as you suspected.

Comment: @bof Good catch. I edited the question a few times. Fixed now.

Comment: " I could just find a really small S, smaller than a x1 where f(x1)=l and if it works for one particular x, "  That makes no sense.  The condition is $x > S \implies$ that means if *any* $x > S$ it is true.  Not just one.  Writing $\forall x \in X$ will have nothing to do with that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will not enter into the details of first order logic, but strictly speaking, if a variable doesn't have a quantifier ($\exists$ or $\forall$) then it is ranging over all the elements of the set.  So, again, strictly speaking both propositions are the same. In fact, strictly speaking, you can safely drop every $\forall x \in X$ whenever you know $X$ is the domain of discourse, it will just annoy your fellow mathematicians but it is *right*.

To see why this is the case, see this example (but remember that this is a formalism about mathematical language, so it is arbitrary in the sense that it was decided by convention to be so): if I am talking about the natural numbers and I say $x$ is even implies $x$ can be divided by $2$, one would reasonable understand that I meant, for all natural numbers $x$, $x$ is even implies it can be divided by 2. Clearly I wasn't talking about one specific $x$.

Again, just remember that this is a (intuitive) convention, nothing more than that.

Answer (score 0):

The meaning of $x>S\implies |f(x)-l|<\epsilon$ is that "if $x>S$ then $|f(x)-l|<\epsilon$". So yes, it **exactly** says that for all $x$ which satisfy $x>S$ we have $|f(x)-l|<\epsilon$. An equivalent way to write the same thing:

$\forall (x: x>S)[|f(x)-l|<\epsilon]$

Note that in this equivalent way I didn't use $\implies$ at all.

Comment: Does this imply I can drop the $\forall x \in X$  in  $\lim_{x \to a} f(x) = l \Leftrightarrow (\forall \epsilon > 0, \exists \delta > 0, \forall x \in X, 0 < |x-a| < \delta \implies |f(x)-l| < \epsilon)$?

Comment: If you know that you are checking the condition for elements of the set $X$ then yes, you can just write $0<|x-a|<\delta\implies |f(x)-l|<\epsilon$. Actually, I always write $\forall(x\in X: 0<|x-a|<\delta)[|f(x)-l|<\epsilon]$. But what I'm saying is that writing the way they did is also fine, as long as you know that you are checking the condition for elements from the set $X$.

Comment: This answer raises a question. According to this convention, WHERE within the expression should $\text{“ }\forall x \text{ ''}$ be? And why?
$$
\begin{array}{ccccc}
\text{here?} & & \text{or here?} & \text{or somewhere else?} \\
\downarrow & & \downarrow & \downarrow \\
\bullet\bullet\bullet & (\forall \varepsilon > 0 \,\,\, \exists \delta > 0 & \bullet\bullet\bullet & 0 < |x-a| < \delta \implies |f(x)-\ell| < \varepsilon)
\end{array}
$$
This matters, since in one case the $\delta$ depends on $x$ (which is NOT as it should be) and in the other it does not. $\qquad$

Comment: Obviously after the $\exists\delta>0$.

Comment: @Mark : That is obvious if you consider the meaning of the limit concept, but how does it follow from conventions of logic?

Comment: That last \downarrow in my comment above should not be there. Here's a correction:
$$
\begin{array}{ccccc}
\text{here?} & & \text{or here?} & \text{or somewhere else?} \\
\downarrow & & \downarrow \\
\bullet\bullet\bullet & (\forall \varepsilon > 0 \,\,\, \exists \delta > 0 & \bullet\bullet\bullet & 0 < |x-a| < \delta \implies |f(x)-\ell| < \varepsilon)
\end{array}
$$
This matters, since in one case the $\delta$ depends on $x$ (which is NOT as it should be) and in the other it does not. $\qquad$